# How to prevent users from downloading whole Firebase database and just all the small parts

Tags: javascript, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My Firebase database is fully readable for anyone, because the content is of course going to be used for a websit. As you know, Firebase has a download limit (10GB/month), and if someone wanted to they could write some code to download the whole thing over and over 'til the limit was reached. Now, can i prevent a full download but still have everything accessible in parts, as intended?

Comment: *"if someone wanted to they could write some code to download the whole thing over and over 'til the limit was reached"* - To be fair, they could also write code to download small parts over and over until the limit was reached.

Comment: I do realize that, but I imagine it would take some more skill and time from a hacker.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Firebase's server-side security rules to limit based on the size of the data users can read at once.

You'll typically control access by making the data not globally readable. Instead you'll want to make it readable by following a certain structure, which matches with how you access the data in your web site.

If you suspect your web site is seeing abuse, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting